# Load data from "File System" rather than "Database"? Modify template file is not working

Tags: database

I am migrating an EE application to a new server. However, it shows the previous version. And if I modify the template file, it's not showing on the site.

Someone said it's because it's loaded from Database rather than File system. I tried to get rid of Database connection. Then it will show nothing.
[image]

Does anyone know what is wrong in this case? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it working. The problem is **$env_config['tmpl_file_basepath']** setting in the config file is wrong. It works after I modified this. Hope this will help someone who need it. Maybe no one will need this. LOL